# Java blocks applet on whitelisted site

Tags: google-chrome, security, browser, java-applet

On the webpage http://smbus.org/faq/crc8Applet.htm there is an applet for demonstrating the calculation of an 8-bit cyclic redundancy check. Java in Chrome and IE on MSWin7 will not allow this to run.
Java gives the error:

> Application Blocked. Click for details.
>
> Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application.

This is even with the Java security level set to the lowest (Medium) and the site **already** added to the *ite exception list.

Clicking reload, does nothing, clicking details shows some kind of read-only java prompt that just shows the java path and a list of flags for some unspecified command.

Java is really starting to tick me off with this carry-on recently. I don't tend to use sites that use applets much but it seems every time that I do I have to deal with this crap.

How can I make Java actually do what it is made to do, i.e. show the darn applet?

EDIT: Java version 7 u67 (build 1.7.0_67-b01)

Just noticed the same problem for the 3D phone viewer on vodafone's website.

Comment: Can you please specify the _exact_ version of java (`java -version`) you are using? Without this information it is difficult to help as java has tightened the securtiy constraints from version to version.